# Why can I not publish my Maui iOS App and how can I fix it?

Tags: ios, maui, publish

I have a Maui app that fails to run on iPad in release mode.  This is running on the latest Visual Studio for MAC.

The splash screen appears for a short while, then just closes the app.

The app runs fine in debug mode in simulators and on my iPhone/iPad.

I am new to Maui and IOS development so have no real idea how to solve this.  I have spent many hours looking for a solution online, but nothing has worked so far.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this as I have a client waiting for their app?

Here is the crash log:

```
{"app_name":"AssetVerifier","timestamp":"2023-05-29 09:44:51.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"9d5a7c8d-689b-3ac4-9e40-182c7ed756c2","adam_id":"6449249070","build_version":"1","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.tbanda.assetverifier","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.4.1 (20E772520a)","roots_installed":0,"name":"AssetVerifier","incident_id":"08193A1F-C436-4642-9CDF-7191619E2F08"}
{
  "uptime" : 360000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad8,9",
  "coalitionID" : 1561,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.4.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20E772520a"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-05-29 09:44:50.5787 -0700",
  "incident" : "08193A1F-C436-4642-9CDF-7191619E2F08",
  "pid" : 5041,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-05-29 09:44:50.0667 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 8747229401222,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 8747241655963,
  "procName" : "AssetVerifier",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/2829FD23-04D0-47C4-996D-6F880906D923\/AssetVerifier.app\/AssetVerifier",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.tbanda.assetverifier","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6449249070","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"4CD95891-234E-4985-A6CC-4ED84F8E9AD8","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"857155187"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.tbanda.assetverifier",
  "crashReporterKey" : "2c2c605b46ce34275d7f9ca8ce666d4f0653d30b",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "throttleTimeout" : 2147483647,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.tbanda.assetverifier",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "GYUSVALXL9",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1636680,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18446744071954212566},{"value":8},{"value":6131690816},{"value":6131688496},{"value":15645619986983673170},{"value":15645619978885897298},{"value":512},{"value":6131688608},{"value":0},{"value":4339063568},{"value":326680576},{"value":2147483648},{"value":328},{"value":8100659456,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":259},{"value":8100659680,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":5780154368},{"value":1},{"value":10741634400},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6131694735},{"value":10767828736}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8246219032},"cpsr":{"value":1073741824},"fp":{"value":6131690832},"sp":{"value":6131690800},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7698101592,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":9414934532}},"name":"tid_103","queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":30040,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":28952,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":119160,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":39383056,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":38907628,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8820,"symbol":"_sigtramp","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":28952,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":119160,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":36478012,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":37771108,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":38745020,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":36512376,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39157360,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":89580,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2220,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1636689,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636692,"name":"SGen worker","frames":[{"imageOffset":5464,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":32888,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":38665240,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636705,"name":"Finalizer","frames":[{"imageOffset":3072,"symbol":"semaphore_wait_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":38225040,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":38093624,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":38093248,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636708,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636709,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636710,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636711,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3204,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":80724,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":81452,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":4552,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":495892,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":500544,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":521436,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":270532,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":270252,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":5045676,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":416,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":374324,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636712,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":1636713,"queue":"com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement","frames":[{"imageOffset":6076,"symbol":"__ulock_wait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":18588,"symbol":"_dlock_wait","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":18000,"symbol":"_dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":79636,"symbol":"__DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":368,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":78528,"symbol":"_dispatch_sync_f_slow","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":3790416,"symbol":"__37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":470260,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":134548,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":661656,"symbol":"__NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":469868,"symbol":"-[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:]","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":6175276,"symbol":"__88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_5","symbolLocation":188,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":122596,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_reply_callout","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":69352,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_call_reply_async","symbolLocation":88,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":16172,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout3","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":138808,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke","symbolLocation":344,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":46092,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":372,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":49368,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4335190016,
    "size" : 41320448,
    "uuid" : "9d5a7c8d-689b-3ac4-9e40-182c7ed756c2",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/2829FD23-04D0-47C4-996D-6F880906D923\/AssetVerifier.app\/AssetVerifier",
    "name" : "AssetVerifier"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4415569920,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "e57f2d6d-f3f1-38fe-a6c2-1fb6f6731d4c",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7698071552,
    "size" : 229368,
    "uuid" : "5998c9ae-c77e-3681-bd6c-0883c89297cf",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8246190080,
    "size" : 49140,
    "uuid" : "b1ee57e1-4484-3714-ba1a-104330ca10c6",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6776229888,
    "size" : 516084,
    "uuid" : "72233fde-ddfe-3e78-b991-2dece8cd78c5",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8245571584,
    "size" : 28656,
    "uuid" : "2e6c66fc-2eb9-34f9-995b-ae0b16e030c4",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_platform.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_platform.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7178776576,
    "size" : 547108,
    "uuid" : "41605dc7-f412-37d1-b51b-fee1a26701e9",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6653513728,
    "size" : 4096000,
    "uuid" : "6a07cbe8-4f65-3dbc-b59d-c1a188a7b95d",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6556286976,
    "size" : 9297920,
    "uuid" : "35567930-fbc2-374b-b44b-1ddfe3ada4a1",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6687518720,
    "size" : 25309184,
    "uuid" : "b0858d8e-7220-37bf-873f-ecc2b0a358c3",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6775939072,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "b74732b5-d7fe-34a4-9346-41945701f020",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8246464512,
    "size" : 270336,
    "uuid" : "7afe0aec-5b9f-3e5d-9803-12ca228ad324",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libxpc.dylib",
    "name" : "libxpc.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6536511488,
  "size" : 2958475264,
  "uuid" : "782f7d5e-1a5f-3231-a200-cf048775184a"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=992.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=992.9M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=624.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=624.9M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           48K        3 \nCoreAnimation                       32K        2 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           596.4M      118 \nMALLOC guard page                  128K        8 \nSTACK GUARD                        160K       10 \nStack                             7440K       10 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       19.8M       31 \n__AUTH                            2245K      223 \n__AUTH_CONST                      27.2M      619 \n__CTF                               824        1 \n__DATA                            11.7M      614 \n__DATA_CONST                      32.1M      625 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      6693K      586 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       313.2M        3 \n__OBJC_RO                         79.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2432K        1 \n__TEXT                           679.7M      636 \ndyld private memory                272K        2 \nmapped file                       53.2M      131 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.8G     3632 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "name" : "tid_103",
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "b4b560f55fed6a6c2f7926c9026b33ce4482c604",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5f72dc58705eff005a46b3a9",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_VIDEO_APP_SELECTION" : "63d867d28283bf1629655506"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000015
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "595d38ea-3211-4d6d-a267-6e13fa65c7de",
      "experimentId" : "641b7ffb89b42413772b9435",
      "deploymentId" : 400000002
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "d28d100b-301c-49ae-b6c9-57930102d4d4",
      "experimentId" : "64466b09a3b9440a82a18c34",
      "deploymentId" : 400000002
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There can be many reasons why this is happening, but there is a good chance you're hitting what is described in [this piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/macios/interpreter).

From the current published version of this doc

> When you compile a .NET Multi-Platform App UI (.NET MAUI) app for iOS or Mac Catalyst, the compiler turns your app code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). When you run the iOS app in the simulator, or the Mac Catalyst app, the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) compiles the MSIL using a Just in Time (JIT) compiler. At runtime the MSIL is compiled into native code, which can run on the correct architecture for your app.
>
> However, there is a security restriction on iOS, set by Apple, which disallows the execution of dynamically generated code on a device. Similarly, the execution of dynamically generated code is disallowed in iOS apps running on the ARM64 architecture in the simulator, and on Mac Catalyst apps running on the ARM64 architecture. To meet this restriction, iOS and Mac Catalyst apps use an Ahead of Time (AOT) compiler to compile the managed code. This produces a native iOS binary that can be deployed to Apple devices, or a native Mac Catalyst binary.

But more importantly, there is this note:

> If your .NET MAUI iOS app or ARM64-based Mac Catalyst app works correctly as a debug build but then crashes as a release build, try enabling the interpreter for your app's release build. It may be that your app, or one of its libraries, uses a feature that requires the interpreter.

### IMPORTANT

While this is easy to enable and enable it for your whole app, make sure you understand what it does. You can also enable the interpreter for certain parts of your app.

Ideally you should enable it ONLY for the parts that are causing issues.

### Enable Mono Interpreter for whole app

To enable the interpreter for your iOS app, add this to your csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For a macOS app, use this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'maccatalyst-arm64' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

### Enable Mono Interpreter for certain assemblies

#### Exclude one assembly

To just exclude one assembly use this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <!-- Interpret everything, except System.Xml.dll -->
    <MtouchInterpreter>all,-System.Xml.dll</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will enable the interpreter for all, but exclude `System.Xml.dll`, which will be compiled AOT.

#### Interpret one assembly

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <!-- AOT everything, except System.Numerics.dll, which will be interpreted -->
    <MtouchInterpreter>-all,System.Numerics.dll</MtouchInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will compile AOT for all binaries, except `System.Xml.dll`, which will not be interpreted.

This is probably the option you should want after you have identified the assembly that is causing issues, which is most likely a plugin.

Finding out which assembly/plugin is causing issues is not really straight-forward unfortunately and comes down to understanding what the interpreter does.